# Value type error in a map that is <String, dynamic>

Tags: dart

I'm trying to construct a https Uri that looks like this:

```
  static Uri accountGetFavoriteMovies(int accountId, LoginInformation loginInfo,
      {int page = 1}) {
    final url = '/account/$accountId/favorite/movies';
    final uri = _resolveUri(
      url,
      query: {
        'api_key': _apiKey,
        'session_id': loginInfo.sessionId,
        'page': page,
      },
    );
    return uri;
  }
```

And what _resolveUri does simply a wrapper to Uri.https constructor:

```
Uri _resolveUri(String path, {Map<String, dynamic>? query}) {
  return Uri.https(
    _authority,
    _basePath + path,
    query,
  );
}
```

Theoretically this should be working fine, but when I tested it, and I got this message:

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type `Iterable<dynamic>`

Where's the problem?

I am convinced the problem is in the query parameter because of this stack:

```
_resolveUri
_AccountUrls.accountGetFavoriteMovies
_AccountRequest.favoriteMoviesRequest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the type for `queryParameters` is `Map<String, dynamic>`, the value expected by `Uri.https` is actually `String` or `Iterable<String>`.

I found this comment in the source code of the `Uri` library on github while trying to debug your question.

> A value in the map must be either a `String`, or an `Iterable` of strings,
> where the latter corresponds to multiple values for the same key.

[Source of the Quote](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/516eb3b05c252ef3d34255d06700c1f09f7f4502/sdk/lib/core/uri.dart#L99)

[Other Comment of Importance](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/516eb3b05c252ef3d34255d06700c1f09f7f4502/sdk/lib/core/uri.dart#L123)